# Defining Class in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why do we define div class name as "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12"? As far as I have seen we define only one class for a div. What is the use of defining 3 classes together for a div ? How it works ?

Comment: It is used in order to specify the required columns for each device, LG Big devices like desktops, MD for tablets and SM for small devices. This is important to get a full responsive clear layout. For more info see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: `col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12` isn't a great example. It can be simplified to `col-md-3 col-sm-12`; see https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Answer (score 1):

Coined from the bootstrap documentation, mixing several grid classes provides a more dynamic and powerful layout that can stack differently across different screen types.